# Move posts under parent page - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I like to move post under parent page, by default WordPress makes them appear from the root homepage ex: http://www.example.com/new-article

I would like to move the articles URL so that they appear under that ex: http://www.example.com/blog/new-article.

Does anyone know how to make WordPress move posts under a specific area/parent page so that the URL would appear as above?

any input would be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to go your dashboard >> Settings >> Permalinks

Select: "Custom Structure" and make your own permalinks by putting

/blog/%postname%/

on the field there.

See for better that what you want.

You can read up here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks
and here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen

Answer (score -1):

Actually I just have realized that this is pretty easy.

In **WordPress >> Setting >>Permalinks** I have changed the permalink structure to *example.com/%category%/%postname%* and got the desired result

Now, I want to edit my category page e.g. *example.com/cat1*. It seems WordPress doesn't allow such thing, am I right?

Answer (score -2):

You should

1. create the page "blog"
2. edit the child page
3. set the parent page via the widget on the right side of the edit screen

Comment: am taking about post, Not for page